# Is Roslyn End User Preview still available?

Tags: roslyn

On the Roslyn home page, there is a link for the "End User Preview" which takes you to the Microsoft Connect site.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/roslyn.aspx

Rather than seeing a form to complete, in order that I can download the end user preview, what I actually see is the "My Dashboard" area. So I search for "rosyln" in the "Product Directory' but no results appear.

Is Roslyn still available for Visual Studio 2013 users as the end user preview, or since Visual Studio 2015 Preview is on the scene, Microsoft have removed that download?

Answer (score 2):

As of today (18 November 2014), the links are once again live.  Apparently, the hosting had a 6-month expiration, which passed without us noticing.

Sorry for the trouble.

However, I will point out that we have *not* updated the Preview for VS2013, so the APIs there are quite out of date, and there are a number of important bugs that have been fixed.  I would recommend using a [VS 2015 Preview](http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/downloads/visual-studio-2015-downloads-vs.aspx) build to look at the .NET Compiler Platform ("Roslyn") instead.

Comment: Thanks for that, much appreciated. It would be better for me to download VS 2015 Preview in that case.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:** You need to click "Downloads" in the top left portion of the screen.

Alternatively you can navigate to the download directly at: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/Downloads/DownloadDetails.aspx?DownloadID=52793

**Edit 2 (2015/01/02)**: It appears the files have been removed again.

**Edit 3 (2015/02/23)**: The files are online again

Comment: That's a shame. Looks like I was very late to the party :)

Comment: Apparently this was not intentional. The Roslyn team is following up internally.