# TaskAwaiter does not implement INotifyCompletion

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, roslyn

I recently installed [Code Connect](http://www.codeconnect.io/) for Visual Studio 2013 and the [Roslyn SDK Preview](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/Downloads/DownloadDetails.aspx?DownloadID=52793), and now in my solution I have nearly 100 build errors stating:

> 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter' does not implement 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.INotifyCompletion'

Has anyone encountered this below? I love the functionality of Code Connect and would rather not have to uninstall it (and the Roslyn SDK Preview is required for Code Connect to function properly).

Comment: Have you tried rebooting after you installed? Sometimes GAC registrations can get wonky after you install or update big parts of VS. Reboots sometimes sort them out.

Comment: I did try both restarting VS and restarting the machine, same errors. Uninstalling the Roslyn Preview extension and rebooting VS did correct the issue so it must be something with Roslyn + VS13. According to a statement [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26975330/is-roslyn-end-user-preview-still-available) there are some major bugs with VS13 that the Roslyn team has not addressed.

Comment: Is this problem present on all solutions? (ie. Does it occur with a brand new Console Application) Also, what version of VS 2013 are you using?

Comment: [Visual Studio 2015](http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/downloads/visual-studio-2015-downloads-vs) can be installed side by side with Visual Studio 2013. It comes with an up to date version of Roslyn which has a lot of bugs fixed. There is [Code Connect for VS 14 and 2015](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/2c025094-2601-450a-8d1b-7786080f0459)

Comment: @Amadeu I was hesitant to install VS2015 as it says not to install it on a machine you aren't able/willing to reformat. I will give it a shot tomorrow though when I have more time to fix if there are issues!